# Access X509 Store in Service Fabric application

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I've put my certificates in `LocalMachine/My` and want to access them thusly:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var x509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbprint, false);
var myCert = x509Certificate2Collection.Count > 0 ? x509Certificate2Collection[0] : null;
store.Close();
```

This works fine on my local cluster, but not on my standalone one.
The certificate I'm trying to access has `NETWORK SERVICE` in ACL for private keys.

I'd assume it's a permissions issue. Am I missing something obvious here?

How can I debug my standalone cluster?

Comment: I would store them in Azure Key vault. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/

Comment: Can't! I need (want) it for Data Protection API - needs cert in cert store for decryption unfortunately :'(

Comment: @PeterBons, the VM Scale set will retrieve and install the certs from KeyVault so you'll avoid a roundtrip by reading it directly from the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works fine. My issue was that my thumbprint was `""` because I hadn't set my config overrides correctly!